# Javascript find all occurrences of name in array of objects and create new unique arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, foreach

I'm trying to get all occurrences from a google calendar in Google Apps Script and create individual arrays for each event name.
Simplified version (example) of response array:

```
{summary=Name1, start={dateTime=2018-12-03T15:00:00+01:00}, end={dateTime=2018-12-03T23:00:00+01:00}},
{summary=Name2, start={dateTime=2018-12-04T11:00:00+01:00}, end={dateTime=2018-12-04T23:00:00+01:00}},
{summary=Name1, start={dateTime=2018-12-05T07:00:00+01:00}, end={dateTime=2018-12-05T15:00:00+01:00}}
```

What I can't figure out is how to filter/split (whatever you'd call it) this up so I'd end up with a new array with the following format:

**EDIT**

```
{Name1=[[2018-12-03, 15, 23, 8.0], [2018-12-04, 11, 23, 12.0], [2018-12-05, 7, 15, 8.0], [2018-12-06, 15, 23, 8.0]], Name2=[[2018-12-11, 7, 16, 9.0], [2018-12-12, 7, 16, 9.0]]}
```

The idea is to then iterate through this new array and do a foreach to get a list of all the dates for individual names.
This is as far as I've gotten

```
function hoursTally() {
  var calendarId = [CALENDAR_ID];
  var startDay = 24;
  var endDay = 23;
  var month = parseFloat(new Date().getMonth()).toFixed(0);
  var year = new Date().getYear();
  var startDate = new Date( year, month-1, startDay );
  var endDate = new Date( year, month, endDay );
  var optionalArgs = {
    timeMin: startDate.toISOString(),
    timeMax: endDate.toISOString(),
    showDeleted: false,
    singleEvents: true,
    orderBy: 'startTime'
  };
  var response = Calendar.Events.list(calendarId, optionalArgs);
  var events = response.items;
   events.forEach(function(e){
     Logger.log(e);
      var name = e.summary;
      var eventDateStart = new Date(e.start.dateTime);
      var eventDateEnd = new Date(e.end.dateTime);
      var startTime = parseFloat(eventDateStart.getHours()).toFixed(0);
      var endTime = parseFloat(eventDateEnd.getHours()).toFixed(0);
      var theDate = Utilities.formatDate(eventDateStart, 'GMT+1', 'yyyy-MM-dd');
      var total = endTime-startTime;
  });
}
```

Every attempt of looping the events and getting the aforementioned format has failed  :(

Comment: `{summary=Name1}` is invalid (at least in JS). It should be `{summary:Name1}`. All `=` inside your objects are syntax errors.

Comment: `{Name1: [2018-12-03, 15, 23, 8], [2018-12-05, 7, 15 8]}` is also invalid because the second element of the object has no key ("Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number"). The desired output is invalid, therefore there is no solution to your problem. You can't get this output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your stated goal is to collect information from each similarly named event into a single summary object, your output data structure should not be an Array of objects - it should just be an associative object. An Array would be appropriate if you wanted equivalent objects to remain distinct, but you state this is not the case.

The solution is then to `reduce` the returned events into an object, where the key of the data is the name, and the value is an array of instance information. The instance information is itself an array (in your example, `[2018-12-03, 15, 23, 8]`)

A simple example which you can adapt to your use case:

```
const summary = items.reduce(function (obj, item) {
  var name = item.summary;
  // If we haven't seen this name before, initialize an empty array
  if (obj[name] === undefined) { obj[name] = []; }
  ...
  // Create an array with the info we want to store
  var info = [
    eventStartDate,
    ...
  ];
  // Store this info array with all the others for the same name
  obj[name].push(info);
  return obj;
}, {});
```

You then use this `summary` by iterating the object:

```
for (var name in summary) {
  summary[name].forEach(function (info) {
    ...
  });
  ...
}
```

[`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm more familiar with PHP, so this was a real challenge :) I'll take some time to try and deconstruct your solution when I have some more time... just to clearly understand what happened ;) Just one question, what is the purpose of const and {} after it?

Comment: @axelra82 From the `Array#reduce` syntax: you may optionally specify the initial value of the accumulator object. If you do not, then the initial value is the first element of the array being processed. Since we want to process the elements of the array--not use them as-is--we don't want the initial value to be the first array element. So, we specify an empty object `{}` as the initial value of the accumulator. Regarding `const`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const (Note that Apps Script does not currently support block scope usage properly.)